# SFINAE to check "template template class" (in template argument) elegantly

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, template-templates

How to check type of a template template class in template argument?

### Example

`B<T>` and `C<T>` are template class.
I want to create a class `D<class BC>` that can be `D<B>` or `D<C>`.
Only `D<B>` has `D::f()`.

Here is my workaround ([demo](http://ideone.com/CmmKnT)). It works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dummy{};
template<class T>class B{};
template<class T>class C{};
template<template<class T> class BC>class D{
    //f() is instantiated only if "BC" == "B"
    public: template<class BCLocal=BC<Dummy>> static
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<BCLocal,B<Dummy>>::value,void>::type f(){  
    }
    //^ #1
};
int main() {
    D<B>::f();
    //D<C>::f();   //compile error as expected, which is good
    return 0;
}
```

The line `#1` is very long and ugly (use `Dummy` to hack).
In real program, it is also error-prone, especially when `B<...>` and `C<...>` can have 5-7 template arguments.

Are there ways to improve it?
I dream for something like :-

```
template<class BCLocal=BC> static
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<BCLocal,B>::value,void>::type f(){ 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just extract the comparison into a handy utility?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class...> class L, template<class...> class R>
struct is_same_temp : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class T>
struct is_same_temp<T, T> : std::true_type {};
```

Then SFINAE on `f` can simply look like this:

```
static auto f() -> typename std::enable_if<is_same_temp<BC, B>::value>::type {
}
```

There't no need to specify `void` for `enable_if` since it's the default type it gives.

And the trailing return type also has a prettifying effect, I think.

---

With C++14, we can prettify further. First a variable template.

```
template<template<class...> class L, template<class...> class R>
using bool const is_same_temp_v = is_same_temp<L, R>::value;
```

Then with the `std::enable_if_t` template alias:

```
static auto f() -> std::enable_if_t<is_same_temp_v<BC, B>> {
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow and [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7da9333cb0a6b95), thank!   Does this technique has a specific name? (other than "template specialization")

Comment: @javaLover - I just noticed the C++14 tag, this can be shortened further, stay tuned

Comment: @javaLover - No name I'm aware of. It's just a regular run-of-the-mill comparison meta-function.

Comment: This is missing a bunch of `class`es.

Comment: @T.C. - What classes and where? I tried to focus on the changes required for `foo`. javaLover was able to apply it successfully to the original example, even linked it above.

Comment: @T.C. - Thank you for the fix. I was completely blind to it.